# Regex select everything between two strings, but not one of the strings

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have some html code that I need to regex and remove a part of it.

In this particular example I need to remove `2-columns.`. The full string is `name="2-columns.Heading-1"` but needs to read `name="Heading-1"`

I would like this to be extendable because another example could be `name="3-columns.Heading-1"`. So I want to remove everything after the starting point of `name="` and the ending `.` (I also want to remove the `.`)

Can anyone help me form the correct regex? I'm struggling.

Comment: You do know that the `name` attribute is only valid for `<form>` and form elements, right?

Comment: @Terry Yes, this is actually for a particular CMS. I said it's html but really it's a handlebar template I'm parsing to replace with this particular CMS's proprietary tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[^"]*\.
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/24

Comment: This worked great. I just had to add the global and multiline tags at the end for to go through the rest of the document. `/[^"]*\./gm` Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

One way;

```
str = str.replace(/(^name=\")(.*\.)/, "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace at group 1:

```
/name="(([^.]+)\.)Heading-1"/
```

Or:

```
'<tag name="2-columns.Heading-1">lalalala</tag>'.replace(/name="(([^.]+)\.)Heading-1"/, 'name="Heading-1"')
```

is:

```
"<tag name="Heading-1">lalalala</tag>"
```

and:

```
'<tag name="2-columns.Heading-2">lalalala</tag>'.replace(/name="(([^.]+)\.)Heading-1"/, 'name="Heading-2"')
```

is:

```
"<tag name="2-columns.Heading-2">lalalala</tag>"
```

---

or:

```
'<tag name="2-columns.Heading-1">lalalala</tag>'.replace(/(name=")(([^.]+)\.)(?=Heading-1")/, "$1");
```